# How can we test app upgrades with Calabash?

Tags: android, ios, calabash

We have been using Calabash to do integration testing for our iOS app (to be used for Android testing as well).

Since we are working on v2 of the app there are certain scenarios that we would like to test work from one version to the other when upgrading. For example, that data is preserved or that certain functionality is enabled automatically on upgrade.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the Calabash iOS side, I recommend using a calabash backdoor command to put your application into an 'upgraded' state.

I have done this on a couple of apps to test the state of the application before and after an IAP.

```
Background: have not upgraded
  Given I have not upgrade to the pro version

Scenario:  after upgrading to pro i should see feature X
  When I upgrade to the pro version
  Then I see X
```

On the Android side, I have no advice.

Comment: It sounds like this type of test could help when someone pays for an upgrade in app, but we are looking for version to version update through a store update without payment.

Comment: @jmoody, how can I put the application an upgraded state using calabash?